# Pg scanning all partitions for non static values

Tags: postgresql

I have simple setup like below with declarative partitioning

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
    foo_id integer NOT NULL,
    page integer
) PARTITION BY RANGE (page);   

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo_0 PARTITION OF foo FOR VALUES FROM (0) TO (1);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo_1 PARTITION OF foo FOR VALUES FROM (1) TO (2);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo_2 PARTITION OF foo FOR VALUES FROM (2) TO (3);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo_3 PARTITION OF foo FOR VALUES FROM (3) TO (4);

--Scans all partitons, Why?
SELECT * FROM foo 
JOIN (SELECT ((2+g)-g) as "P" FROM generate_series(0,100) as g) as "T" ON "T"."P"=page

--Correctly Scans only required partition
SELECT * FROM foo 
JOIN (SELECT 2 as "P" FROM generate_series(0,100) as g) as "T" ON "T"."P"=page
```

Question is why does PG scan all partitions for first Query and scans correct partition for the second one?

A bit of doc reading tells me it may do it on run time, but i fails to see that happing when i run explain analyse verbose
What am i missing?

Comment: Why? Because the optimizer can't see that the query `SELECT ((2+g)-g) as "P" FROM generate_series(0,100) as g` returns the same value for all rows.

Comment: Should it not be trying to infer that? Else partitioning works only in case of static values would that be a correct staement?

Comment: I mean even when i have a table with values and i join it it still scans all partitions which makes partitioning useless or less effective? Or is there any better way to write this query?

Comment: Even if i write "between" which is always single value doesnt help so i dont think its multiple rows problem..

Comment: Partitioning isn't primarily a performance tool. It doesn't magically make everything faster just because you partition it. In your case an index on a  non-partitioned table might be a better choice. A join with a partitioned table will only use partition pruning if the joined table is partitioned by the same strategy

Comment: Can you shed some light on this sentence or an example trying to understand this better, 'A join with a partitioned table will only use partition pruning if the joined table is partitioned by the same strategy'                The above is just a an example the real table cotains per second records for a 3 years from multiple sensors so i guess i will need partitioning  need this Join to work for a specifc usecase

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c9980f4267c15e7357ad5b6a316aaa77  - watch out for the lines in the execution plan that have `(never executed)` which means that runtime partition pruning was used

Comment: Nice thanks this helps, never knew of tht setting will try out this..

Comment: How can this be worked out with subquery?, i mean Join with a table having partition is good what if the LHS or RHS of the join is a subquery.. thinking loud does over clause help?